# Can you login to Bloomberg via R when the user is logged off on the workstation?

Tags: r, bloomberg, blpapi

How can one login to Bloomberg via R when the user is logged off on the workstation?  The workflow is that during off-hours a batch file will run via task scheduler to gather some data from Bloomberg when the user is not logged in to the machine.

I have seen some posts regarding a username / password option available with blpConnect when using the older RBloomberg package (no longer available). I am using Rblpapi.  Appreciate any ideas that have worked for folks in past.

Comment: I don't think so. BTW, `Rblpapi::blpConnect()` also has user/passwd options.

Comment: As long as the user doesn't log in somewhere else (if it's a Bloomberg anywhere account), you should be fine (no need for the terminal to be logged in). If the user logs in on his mobile for example, then there is not much you can do.

Comment: Does anyone know the format for the user/password options with Rblpapi?  Don't see this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Using Desktop API - you can't. Using Server API and B-PIPE, you can. To quote the [documentation](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/content/uploads/sites/2/2014/07/blpapi-developers-guide-2.54.pdf):

> The authentication and permissioning systems of Server API and Managed B-PIPE require use of the //blp/apiauthservice. This defines the requests and responses that will come from the API.